# Сохранение динамического контента

Tags: javascript, php

столкнулся с такой проблемой:

На сайте n есть подменяемый контент, пусть будет к примеру номер телефона в шапке сайта, который меняется в зависимости от utm метки по которой пришел пользователь, собственно проблема заключается в том, что-бы показывать пользователю подмененный контент постоянно, то есть при переходе на другую страницу и так далее. Собственно, как это можно реализовать? Я новичок во всем этом, по этому для меня это все не очень понятно

Comment: либо при приходе новой utm пишите где то себя в БД соответствие данной метки с тем, что выводить. Либо например в куку записываете выбранный для вывода вариант. Если пользователь пришел без куки - решаете что вывести и пишите нужную куку. А если с кукой то вы по ней определяете что выводить

Comment: Полностью согласен, юзай куки